Footnote in dedicatory in the amsart document class
As the title says, I would like to add a footnote in the dedicatory which I use for a quotation in the amsart document class but the output is not as desired. The footnote is placed nowhere. I don't care if the footnote is placed on the cover page or on the next page but preferably on the title page - at least it should be placed somewhere unlike now.
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Dein Titel}
\author{Dein Name}
\dedicatory{Faire de l'Algèbre, c'est essentiellement calculer.\foonote{\cite{bibtextentry}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


Your example stops with ! Undefined control sequence. \@dedicatory ...essentiellement calculer.\foonote

Maybe you need to load a package so that these commands are available @DavidCarlisle

No. You need to test your example before posting.

Sorry  I'll check and edit

\fooTnote ....
apart from that, the usual way to handle footnotes in special constructs is to use \footnotemark at the point you want the mark in the text and then use \footnotetext anywhere outside the special box, so that it can migrate to the page breaker.
Here though \footnotemark is disabled; probably related to \thanks and other title specific annotations, so I just used \textsuperscript

\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Dein Titel}
\author{Dein Name}
\dedicatory{Faire de l'Algèbre, c'est essentiellement calculer.\textsuperscript{1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\footnotetext[1]{\cite{bibtextentry}}
\end{document}


Do you think this will count with several footnotes. Like the next gets a 2

You probably need to add the counter

Thank you very much

Also I think the font of the footnote is emphasized. Dunno if this is intended

But I can continue to work from this
